# Is the pointwise infimum of this convex function convex?

Tags: random-variables, convex-analysis, expected-value

In this text regarding certain risk measures: http://www.pacca.info/public/files/docs/public/finance/Active%20Risk%20Management/gpfl.pdf
it is pointed out in the proof of Proposition 2 that since the map
\begin{align}
 \phi(x, y) := max(y-x, 0) 
\end{align}
is convex in $y$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that the operator

\begin{align}
\rho(X) := \inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \{ y + E[ \max(X-y, 0)] \}
\end{align}
is convex in $X$,  where $X$ is a random variable.
This seems slightly surprising, since we are taking the pointwise infimum.

As far as I can tell, by convexity of $\phi$ and monotonicity of $E[\cdot]$ we get that
\begin{align}
g(X, y) := E[ \phi(X,y)] 
\end{align}
is convex in X: Given random variables $X, Y$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$,
\begin{align}
g(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y - y) &= E[\phi(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y, y)]\\
&\leq E[\lambda \phi(X, y) + (1-\lambda)\phi(Y, y)]. 
\end{align}
But if $g(X, y)$ is convex in $X$ for each y, why is $\inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\{y + g(X, y)\}$ convex in $X$? Can we simply say that
\begin{align}
 \inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\{y + g(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y, y)\} \leq  \inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\{y + \lambda g(X, y) +  (1-\lambda)g(Y, y)\}?
\end{align}

Comment: By pointwise convexity, $g(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y, y)\leq\lambda g(X, y) +  (1-\lambda)g(Y, y)$ for each $y$. Now add $y$ to both sides and take $\inf$ on both sides. Infimum of a smaller function will be smaller.

Comment: So essentially, the argument in the last equation is correct and shows convexity - or did I misunderstand you reply?

Comment: The last equation is correct, but it does not show that $\inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\{y + g(X, y)\}$ is convex. For that you'd need to split the infimum on the right in two and that would be false. Pointwise infimum of even two convex functions need not be convex, as you can see with parabolas, let alone of a whole family of them.

Comment: I see, of course! But when doing as you propose, by first using the convexity and only later adding y and taking the infimum, we get the desired inequality - did I understand you correct then? And thanks. If you were to write up your answer as a comment, I'd gladly accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was only commenting on the last inequality. Now that I looked, I do not really follow what they are doing in the proof and whether this inequality is enough for it.